# migrating to mac makes word read only

Tags: read-only

Used migration assistant to transfer my files from windows seven computer to a Mac mini.
 all went well except all my Word files are read only. Word invites me to duplicate and then refuses to do so. Cites possible possible ;permissions issue

Comment: 1) Are only the word files RO or all files in the folder with the word files? What happens if you try to create a new file (not nessecary word, could be a simple text file, e.g. cd to the folder and `touch testfile`.
2) If it is only a problem with the copied files then check who you are and who the owner of those files is (e.g. `ls -l *` in the folder with the word files. Is that the same user as who logged in on the Mac? Group rwx set ro r only? etc etc

Comment: Or, if you're not comfortable with Terminal, select one file, right click & Get Info. Make sure it shows you as Owner & staff or admin as Group. I've seen this happen if the migrate wasn't done at the same time as the initial set up. You end up with 2 distinct users rather than one... & your file belongs to the other.